# Python Regex - Create explicit multiplication

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace implicit multiplication in strings (such as "ax") with explicit multiplication (such as "a*x"). I have most of it done, except I also wanted to add it to replace something such as "a(x+1)" with "a*(x+1)".

So far, my pattern is:

```
pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+|[a-z\)])([a-z\(])", re.IGNORECASE)
```

I am using `pattern.sub` to do the actual replacing:

```
s = "RX(3X)R"
print pattern.sub('\\1*\\2', s)
```

However, it does not replace "a(" with "a*(". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lookahead assertion:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+|[a-z\)])(?=[a-z\(])", re.IGNORECASE)
>>> s = "RX(3X)R"
>>> print pattern.sub('\\1*', s)
R*X*(3*X)*R
```

The problem with your regex is that your pattern matches `RX` and then inserts a `*`.  However, you can't then match `X` again to insert a `*` between `X(`.  If you use a lookahead, then you don't consume the `X` so it is available to be matched as part of another expression.  Of course, here the sub pattern needs to change too since there is no second group.